# Lazy ByteString built from Socket handle cannot be consumed and GCed lazily

Tags: sockets, memory, haskell, lazy-evaluation, bytestring

I'm writing a network file transfer application. Using Lazy ByteString as a intermediate

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
```

When constructing a BSL from local file, then put the BSL to a Handle of Socket:

```
BSL.readFile filename >>= BSL.hPut remoteH  -- OK
```

This works fine. Memory usage is constant. But for receiving data from Socket, then write to local file:

```
BSL.hGet remoteH size >>= BSL.hPut fileH bs  -- starts swapping in 1 second
```

I can see memory usage keep going up, BSL takes **size** bytes of memory. 
Worse, for large **size** that exceeded my physical memory size, OS starts swapping immediately.

I have to receive segments of ByteStrings recursively. That is OK.

Why **BSL** behave like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hGet` is strict -- it immediately demands the number of bytes you requested. It does this in order to facilitate packet level reading of data.

However, `hGetContentsN` is lazy, and `readFile` is implemented in terms of `hGetContentsN`.

Consider the two implementations:

```
hGetContentsN :: Int -> Handle -> IO ByteString
hGetContentsN k h = lazyRead -- TODO close on exceptions
  where
    lazyRead = unsafeInterleaveIO loop

    loop = do
        c <- S.hGetSome h k -- only blocks if there is no data available
        if S.null c
          then do hClose h >> return Empty
          else do cs <- lazyRead
                  return (Chunk c cs)
```

and

```
hGet :: Handle -> Int -> IO ByteString
hGet = hGetN defaultChunkSize

hGetN :: Int -> Handle -> Int -> IO ByteString
hGetN k h n | n > 0 = readChunks n
  where
    STRICT1(readChunks)
    readChunks i = do
        c <- S.hGet h (min k i)
        case S.length c of
            0 -> return Empty
            m -> do cs <- readChunks (i - m)
                    return (Chunk c cs)
```

The key magic is the laziness in `hGetContentsN`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer authoritatively on the behavior of lazy bytestrings, but I would recommend that you look into some kind of streaming approach, like [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) or [enumerator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/enumerator). With conduit, you could write something like:

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Binary

main = do
    let filename = "something"
    remoteH <- getRemoteHandle
    runResourceT $ sourceHandle remoteH $$ sinkFile filename
```

You can also bypass the `Handle` abstraction entirely if you wish by using [network-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-conduit) and something like:

```
runResourceT $ sourceSocket socket $$ sinkFile filename
```